# flutter shows null in list view but when printed it shows the data

Tags: flutter

I am using cubit and clean architecture for my flutter project and I am trying to integrate get method and display the data in the screen, problem is after I integrate my get method which is successful btw, it even shows 200 status code but when I try to display it in my using Listview Builder screen it shows null, but when I print my response the responses are printed successfully, and since I am using clean architecture my codes are divided into multiple files so putting all code might be a hassle so if anyone has any idea, you are more that welcome.

[image: this is my response.data]

**this is screen page**

```
class DashboardPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const DashboardPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => getIt<HomeDataCubit>()..getHomeData(),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          title: const AppBars(),
        ),
        body: BlocBuilder<HomeDataCubit, HomeDataState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            return state.maybeWhen(
                orElse: () => Container(
                      height: 90,
                      width: size.width,
                      color: Colors.brown,
                    ),
                loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                success: (data) {
                  final response = data;
                  return Scaffold(
                    body: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: response.data.grievance.length,
                        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                          return Container(
                            width: size.width,
                            height: 90,
                            color: Colors.green,
                          );
                        }),
                  );
                });
          },
        ),
```

**this is cubit**

```
part 'home_data_state.dart';
part 'home_data_cubit.freezed.dart';

@injectable
class HomeDataCubit extends Cubit<HomeDataState> {
  HomeDataCubit(this._useCase) : super(const HomeDataState.initial());
  final HomeDataUseCase _useCase;

  Future<void> getHomeData() async {
    emit(const HomeDataState.loading());
    final response = await _useCase.call(
      const NoParam(),
    );
    emit(
      response.fold(
        (error) => error.when(
          serverError: (message) => HomeDataState.error(message: message),
          noInternet: () => const HomeDataState.noInternet(),
        ),
        (response) => HomeDataState.success(data: response),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**this is state**

```
part of 'home_data_cubit.dart';

@freezed
class HomeDataState with _$HomeDataState {
  const factory HomeDataState.initial() = _Initial;

  const factory HomeDataState.loading() = _Loading;

  const factory HomeDataState.noInternet() = _NoInternet;

  const factory HomeDataState.error({required String message}) = _Error;

  const factory HomeDataState.success(
      {required ApiResponse<HomeDataListModels> data}) = _Success;
}
```

**this is repo**

```
abstract class HomeDataRepository {
  Future<Either<AppError, ApiResponse<HomeDataListModels>>> getHomeData();
}
```

**this is usecase**

```
@lazySingleton
class HomeDataUseCase
    extends UseCase<ApiResponse<HomeDataListModels>, NoParam> {
  HomeDataUseCase(this._repository);

  final HomeDataRepository _repository;
  @override
  Future<Either<AppError, ApiResponse<HomeDataListModels>>> call(
          NoParam params) =>
      _repository.getHomeData();
}
```

**this is source**

```
abstract class HomeDataSource {
  Future<ApiResponse<HomeDataListModels>> getHomeData();
}

@LazySingleton(as: HomeDataSource)
class HomeDataSourceImpl implements HomeDataSource {
  const HomeDataSourceImpl(@Named('authenticated') Dio dio) : _dio = dio;
  final Dio _dio;

  @override
  Future<ApiResponse<HomeDataListModels>> getHomeData() async {
    try {
      final response = await _dio.get('home');
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print('thic contains $response');
        return ApiResponse(
          data: HomeDataListModels.fromJson(response.data),
          message: 'message',
        );
      } else {
        throw AppException(
            message: response.data?['message'] ?? 'UnKnown Error');
      }
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      throw AppException(message: e.message);
    }
  }
}
```

**this is repos**

```
@LazySingleton(as: HomeDataRepository)
class HomeDataRepositoryImpl implements HomeDataRepository {
  HomeDataRepositoryImpl(this._networkInfo, this._remoteSource);

  final HomeDataSource _remoteSource;
  final NetworkInfo _networkInfo;

  @override
  Future<Either<AppError, ApiResponse<HomeDataListModels>>>
      getHomeData() async {
    if (await _networkInfo.isConnected) {
      try {
        final response = await _remoteSource.getHomeData();
        return right(ApiResponse(
          data: response.data,
          message: response.message,
          errors: response.errors,
        ));
      } on AppException catch (e) {
        return left(AppError.serverError(message: e.message));
      }
    } else {
      return left(
        const AppError.noInternet(),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

**this is models**

```
part 'home_data_lists_models.freezed.dart';
part 'home_data_lists_models.g.dart';

@freezed
class HomeDataListModels with _$HomeDataListModels {
  @JsonSerializable(fieldRename: FieldRename.snake, explicitToJson: true)
  const factory HomeDataListModels({
    String? image,
    int? id,
    String? introdesc,
    String? missiondesc,
    int? ward_id,
    @Default([]) List<String> gallery,
    @Default([]) List<GrivenceModels> grievance,
    @Default([]) List<StructureModels> structure,
  }) = _HomeDataListModels;
  factory HomeDataListModels.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$HomeDataListModelsFromJson(json);
}
```

Comment: hi, please put the code you are using to let me help you

Comment: thanks, I Checked your code, and please print response.data and send me the print data, after that I give you what's wrong

Comment: @Amirali_Eric_J, I added the image of response.data, please check

Comment: please change  HomeDataListModels.fromJson(response.data) to  HomeDataListModels.fromJson(response.data['response']) and let me know what is happening, if it was ok let me know to put the answer in this page, if it was not ok it is because of fetching your json in fromJson

Comment: @Amirali_Eric_J, it worked perfectly fine sir, I can't thank u enough ;)

Comment: you're welcome my friend. i'll put the answer and please vote it up and mark it as correct answer to help another people. I'm happy that I could solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we talked together in the comments, you are receiving your response correctly, but you can't fetch the data to show them.
if you pay attention to your response you'll see:

```
{
  "message" : "Data Available",
  "response" : {
    
     "cms" : ///// and another datas///

}

}
```

here is the way that you should do to fetch your data in a correct way, because you need `response` part of your `json`:

```
abstract class HomeDataSource {
  Future<ApiResponse<HomeDataListModels>> getHomeData();
}

@LazySingleton(as: HomeDataSource)
class HomeDataSourceImpl implements HomeDataSource {
  const HomeDataSourceImpl(@Named('authenticated') Dio dio) : _dio = dio;
  final Dio _dio;

  @override
  Future<ApiResponse<HomeDataListModels>> getHomeData() async {
    try {
      final response = await _dio.get('home');
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print('this contains $response');
        return ApiResponse(
          // data: HomeDataListModels.fromJson(response.data),
          data: HomeDataListModels.fromJson(response.data['response']),
          message: 'message',
        );
      } else {
        throw AppException(
            message: response.data?['message'] ?? 'UnKnown Error');
      }
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      throw AppException(message: e.message);
    }
  }
}
```

happy coding my friend...